# Angular view affecting rest call

Tags: angularjs, rest, jersey

When I try to make a call to my server, I get a 404 error. I previously tried doing this without using route provider (for different views), and it **worked successfully.** All of the code is pretty much the same, except for the addition of a new view.

My current URL to the page that requires the http get is http://localhost:8080/projectname/#/page1

This is the call itself (seen below)

var response = $http.get('/projectname/webapi/object/');

I'm guessing that there is something wrong with my path, but I'm not sure.

Please excuse any typos, as I covered up  names of some items...

java script

```
var Demo = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
     .when("/page1",{
                templateUrl:"include/Templates/page1.html",
                controller:"TestController"
})
    .when("/page2",{
                templateUrl:"include/Templates/page2.html",
                controller:"Test2Controller"
})
.otherwise({redirectTo: "/page1"});
})
.controller("TestController", function ($scope, $filter, $http){

     var app = this;
        $scope.operation="";
        $scope.isSaveDisabled = true;
        $scope.isDeleteDisabled = true;

        var response = $http.get('/projectname/webapi/object/');
        response.success(function(data) {
          $scope.data = data;
          console.log($scope);
          angular.forEach(data, function(element) {
          });
        })
        response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("AJAX failed to get data, status=" + status);
        }) 
        ...
```

Object Resource

```
  @Path("/object")
   public class objectResource {

   objectService objectService = new objectService();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<object> getobject() {
    return objectService.getAllobject();
}

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<object> getChangedobject(List<object> object) {
    System.out.println(letter);

    return objectService.getChangedobject(object);
 }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
 see implementation details                        http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-   class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>package.project</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is this `{redirectTo: "//page1"}` one of the typos you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, sorry.The redirect works. The page loads, but the call fails.

Comment: can you post the complete url , that is being called by angular get.

Comment: It may be the case that it is actually making a call to /page1/projectname/webapi/object